# Probability that output is result of the same process?

Tags: monte-carlo, algorithms, similarities

I've developed a simple [Monte-Carlo simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method). Output of this simulation is a histogram. This histogram is possibly a log-normal distribution, but I don't want to assume that. But I do know that the histogram is "smooth" and that there won't be any spikes. I would like to create an "automated test" that makes sure that the algorithm works properly and to give others idea about what appropriate output of the simulation is, given some input parameters.

To begin with, I will run the simulation in high-fidelity, producing "smooth" and precise output histogram. This will be "reference" histogram.
Then, for the test, the simulation will be run in low fidelity and compared against the reference. From this comparison, I would like to know "how is it likely, that same algorithm produced this output as the reference output".

Right now, only thing I can think of is to treat the histogram as vectors and calculate "distance" between them. But I'm, not sure this is the best approach.

Next step would be to have multiple pairs (no more than few dozen) of reference and test histograms and calculate the "sameness" probability from all of them.

This approach would give me a single number, that I could compare against some threshold and warn if it gets bellow that threshold.

Also, if it is not obvious, the whole testing algorithm should be fully automated and not require any human intervention or input. And it should be relatively fast (eg. it should not run the simulation more than is really necessary).

Comment: An histogram is never "smooth" in that it always produces a step function, constant on the sequence of interval and counting the number of occurrences of realisations within each interval. Testing for goodness of fit can be done by a Kolmogorov-test if the exact probabilities of each interval are known.